# How to get checked rows' values from html table on a sidebar using GAS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a table whose rows consist of 3 columns. 1º is a checkbox, 2º contains the colors and the 3º contains the hex.

As the user selects the colors desired by ticking the checkboxes, i imagine the colors being pushed into an arrat, that will be written to a cell as the user clicks on the save button.

I've borrowed this snippet from Mark, but it doesn't seem to run in my context:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
var selectedRows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    checkbox.onclick = function() {
        var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        selectedRows.push(secondColumn);
    };
    console.log(selectedRows)
}
```

This is the `javascript` part running to load and populate the table and I'm not sure where the above snippet woud go into:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Run initializations on sidebar load.
   */
  $(function() {
    // Assign handler functions to sidebar elements here, if needed.

    // Call the server here to retrieve any information needed to build
    // the dialog, if necessary.
google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function (record) {   //<-- with this
          showRecord(record);
        })
        .withFailureHandler(
          function(msg, element) {
            showStatus(msg, $('#button-bar'));
            element.disabled = false;
          })
        .getRecord();
  });
  /**
   * Callback function to display a "record", or row of the spreadsheet.
   *
   * @param {object[]}  Array of field headings & cell values
   */
  function showRecord(record) {
    if (record.length) {
      
      for (var i = 0; i < record.length-1; i++) {
        // Adds a header to the table
        if(i==0){
           $('#sidebar-record-block').append($($.parseHTML('<div class="div-table-row"><div class="div-table-header">Sel</div><div class="div-table-header">Color</div><div class="div-table-header">Hex</div></div>')));
      }
        // build field name on the fly, formatted field-1234
        var str = '' + i;
        var fieldId = 'field-' + ('0000' + str).substring(str.length)

        // If this field # doesn't already exist on the page, create it
        if (!$('#'+fieldId).length) {
          var newField = $($.parseHTML('<div id="'+fieldId+'"></div>'));
          $('#sidebar-record-block').append(newField);
        }

        // Replace content of the field div with new record
        $('#'+fieldId).replaceWith('<div id="'+fieldId+'" class="div-table-row"></div>');
        $('#'+fieldId).append('<input type="checkbox" class="div-table-td" id=CB"'+fieldId+'"name="checkBox" </input>')
                      .append($('<div class="div-table-td">' + record[i].heading + '</div>'))
                      .append('<div class="div-table-td">' + record[i].cellval + '</div>')             
      }  
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So your current js code pulls data from Apps Script and populates an html table and what you want to do is to capture the event a a checkbox being ticked?

Comment: hi, @ziganotschka! The ultimate goal is to get 2º column data from the checked checkboxes into an array and pass this array into a cell.

Comment: Be careful with your checkbox ids if you plan on using them. In each loop you create a checkbox with the same id `checkBox`. "Mark's snippet" has a click event that does something when the checkboxes are being clicked, in your case you need to tie the funcitonality to the save button click event.

Comment: I will have to differentiate it so that it can be used later as an identity to the row, correct, @ziganotschka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sample of how to get the checked tickboxes an button click

- Assuming all your checkboxes are tied to a row, you can [loop](https://api.jquery.com/each/) through all checkboxes with a [query selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/),
- access their [checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) status
- and save the indices of those checkboxes.
- Those indices will be the same as when looping through the corresponding table rows.

Sample implementing a button [click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/):

```js
var saveButton = document.getElementById("myButtonId"); 
saveButton.onclick = function(){
  var checkedRowIndices = []; 
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function( index ) {
    if($(this)[0].checked{
      checkedRowIndices.push(index);
    }
  }); 
};
//now get the rows with those indeices and do something with them
```

Comment: Hi! Why is this giving me ```length``` 0 ```checkedRowIndices```, even though I got some checkboxes ticked?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. Maybe you can implement logs both wihtin the `each` loop and the `if` condition to see where it fails. Otherwise, providing your full (relevant) html might help.

Comment: This one worked for me: ```var saveButton = document.getElementById("myButtonId"); saveButton.onclick = function(){
   var checkedRowIndexes = []; 
  var selectedColors = []; 
  var checkedRows = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
  for (var i = 0; i < checkedRows.length; i++){
    if (checkedRows[i].checked){
    checkedRowIndexes.push(i);
    }
  }
  console.log(checkedRowIndexes);
}```

Comment: Hello @AntonioSantos! I just noticed, I had a typo, sorry about this! It should be `$(this)[0].checked`  and not `$(this).checked` because without the [0] one would try to get the `checked` property of the jquery object instead of the actual element. Your solution without jquery is just as valid, I am glad it works for you.

Comment: Appreciate your help, as this pointed me to the right direction!